# Trying to put a Docker image on AWS ECR

Tags: python, docker, amazon-ecr

I'm trying to build a Docker image, and be able to push it into an AWS ECR container. I do this with the aim of being able to deploy a SpaCy model that I have already trained on a Jupyter's notebook and hosted in S3.
When I execute the commands in the terminal to be able to create the image, and push it to the container, this appears in the terminal:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cov6.png)

The commands that I have executed in the terminal are the ones that appear in the AWS ECR console, which are:

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region eu-central-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 656621596830.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
```

```
docker build -t ner .
```

```
docker tag ner:latest 656621596830.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/ner:latest
```

```
docker push 656621596830.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/ner:latest
```

I have executed these commands in the local directory that I use to create the image, which is the following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkL31.png)

The 'inference.py' file contains the following code:

```
import spacy
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
import string
import es_core_news_sm

model_local_path = './model/modelo.tar.gz'

def process_text(text):
    
    # LA FUNCION PROCESA EL TEXTO RECIBIDO ANTES DE ENVIARLO AL MODELO
    frasesSolicitud = sent_tokenize(text)
    
    
    frasesProcesadas = []
    nlp = es_core_news_sm.load() # Cargo el modelo entrenado en memoria

    for frase in frasesSolicitud:
        frasesSinVerbos = []
        texto = frase.lower()
        texto = texto.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
        
        doc = nlp(texto)
        #print(doc)
        for palabra in doc:
            print(palabra, palabra.pos_)
            if palabra.pos_ != 'VERB' and palabra.pos_ != 'ADJ' and palabra.pos_ != 'PRON':
                frasesSinVerbos.append(str(palabra))
        else:
            #print(frasesSinVerbos)
            textoSinVerbos = ' '.join(frasesSinVerbos)
            frasesProcesadas.append(textoSinVerbos)



        productosReconocidos = []
    
        nlp1 = spacy.load(model_local_path)
        for item in frasesProcesadas:
            fraseProcesada = item.lower()
            doc = nlp1(fraseProcesada)

            spacy.displacy.render(doc, style="ent", jupyter=True)
                # Extraer las etiquetas de las entidades nombradas detectadas
            for item in doc.ents:
                productosReconocidos.append(item.label_)
    
        return productosReconocidos

if __name__ == '__main__':
    listaProductos = process_text('This is an example of sentence.')
```

This code should be able to access the trained model. A function is defined with a parameter, which is processed and thrown against the model. If the model recognizes any entity with which it was trained, it adds it to 'productosReconocidos'. When a call is made to the endpoint and a text is passed to it, the output of the model should be a list with the recognized entities.

The 'Dockerfile' file contains the following code:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

RUN pip install spacy
RUN pip install nltk

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    build-essential \
    libatlas-base-dev \
    libopencv-dev \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev \
    libssl-dev

RUN python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm

# No será necesario por el momento un archivo requirements.txt.
#COPY requirements.txt /opt/ml/code/requirements.txt
#RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /opt/ml/code/requirements.txt

COPY inference.py inference.py

ENV SAGEMAKER_PROGRAM inference.py
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED TRUE

ENTRYPOINT ["python", "inference.py"]
```

Please, it's my first time using Docker and ECR, so I understand that I'm making some mistakes. Thank you very much for your patience.

All the best!

Comment: HI DaveDEV! You didn't mention any problem. Or which portion of the code isn't working.

Comment: Hi Rafaf! The point is that I couldn't push the image to ECR container, because of the cli output that appears on the first image. However, I have fix it. Apparently the error was caused by using a different account on Docker than the one I'm using on AWS. I don't want to delete the question to edit it in a few days explaining what has worked for me. I know I don't have a lot of experience, but I'd be glad to hear that someone has found my solution helpful. Thanks mate!